# Post JSON data (characteres with accents) with EXTJS and save with PHP

Tags: php, extjs, unicode

Sorry for my English, I'm Braziliam.

In one of my forms, I send datas in array to php save in db... I type de word "8º ANDAR" and extjs send to php "8\u00ba ANDAR" (no problem until here), but how I revert the "8\u00ba ANDAR" to "8º ANDAR" with php?

I tryed, but no success...
[Here my post data with ExtJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpEJe.png)
Here is my code in php:

```
if(in_array($_POST['action'], array('INSERIR', 'EDITAR')) and isset($_POST['ambientes'])){
    $ambientes = json_decode(stripcslashes('['.$_POST['ambientes'].']'), true);
    foreach ($ambientes as $key => $item) {
        //need to revert the $nome_ambiente....
        $nome_ambiente = mb_strtoupper(trim($item['ambiente']));
        $nome_ambiente = ReformatString($nome_ambiente);
        $nome_ambiente = preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $nome_ambiente);
        $nome_ambiente = preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]/', ' ', $nome_ambiente);

        $obs_ambiente = mb_strtoupper($item['observacoes'], 'UTF-8');
        $obs_ambiente = ReformatString($obs_ambiente);

        $sqlA = "SELECT count(*) FROM ambientes_nomes WHERE descricao='$nome_ambiente'";
        $pdoA = $connection->prepare($sqlA);
        $pdoA->execute();
        $num_rows = $pdoA->fetchColumn();

        if($num_rows < 1){
            $sqlB = "INSERT INTO ambientes_nomes (descricao, cadastrado_por, alterado_por, data_cadastro, data_alteracao) VALUES ('$nome_ambiente', $user_id, $user_id, '$data_atual', '$data_atual')";
            $pdoB = $connection->prepare($sqlB);
            $pdoB->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I revert the "8\u00ba ANDAR" to "8º ANDAR" with php?

`json_decode('['.$_POST['ambientes'].']', true)`

Comment: Thank you. I was using $ambientes = json_decode(stripcslashes('['.$_POST['ambientes'].']'), true); and was not working

Comment: the `stripcslashes()` was invalidating the Unicode entity.